# What is the exact walking distance colonists can travel between domes?

Tags: surviving-mars

I don't have a shuttle tech but I want to relocate some colonists. One of two domes is on an elevated hill so I'm not sure if a new dome downhill will suffice.
What is the **exact** maximum number of tiles two domes can have between them and still allow migration between them without shuttles?

Comment: Do you have a tunnel near the domes ?

Comment: The question was created before tunnels existed. How is that relevant? Tunnel distance is much smaller anyway

Comment: Well you said that a dome is on an elevated hill, you can put the entry of a tunnel close to the first dome and the exit close to the second one

Comment: Oh, I confused tunnels with passages. I thought about passages. Thank you, I know that I can, but the question is not about that. Also it was a hill that didn't need a tunnel to get to, just a small elevation with ramp leading to it.

Comment: Ok then, I don't have the answer to your question but I saw that colonists can migrate between domes on foot if they won't lack of oxygen on the road (patchnote : Spirit update : Colonists will no longer try to walk kilometers on foot to resettle resulting in them dying from lack of oxygen)

Answer (score 1):

The maximum length of a passage is 18 tiles. I'm not 100% sure if that includes the end spaces or not, so it might be a reliable maximum of 14 hexes between domes (+1 for each entryway and +1 for each wall hex they build through). Colonists will relocate any distance as long as there is a fully connected network of domes and passages. (They'll only work/seek services 1 passage away, but they'll migrate any distance.)

I don't know if they'll even bother walking outside to migrate, but if they do I STRONGLY suspect they won't go further than the building radius (displayed as a highlighted border when selecting the dome), same as they would for work.